# Display column with histograms from skimr when using xtable()

Tags: r, xtable, skimr

Could I also display the column with the histograms when creating the xtable from

```
SK<-data.frame(skimr::skim(iris[,1:4]))
```

to

```
htmlTable::htmlTable(xtable(SK, result="html"))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? I don't get it. Works just fine, output displayed in Viewer: `library(xtable); SK <- data.frame(skimr::skim(iris[,1:4])); SKmod <- SK[,c('skim_variable', 'numeric.hist')]; htmlTable::htmlTable(xtable(SKmod, result="html"))`

Comment: if you view SK histograms are displayed in the last column. Not with htmlTable though